# How to list all guild members in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to list all users from specified server on bot start, I'm using discord.js v12.5.1

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.id === "my guild id");
guild.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.username));
```

The error I receive:

```
guild.members.forEach(member => console.log(member));
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
```

How to solve this? How could I list all guild members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guild.members` is a [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) so you either need to use its `.cache` or [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) the members.

Another error is that `member`s don't have a `username` property, only `user`s have, so you need to use `member.user.username` instead:

```js
const id = 'YOUR_ID';
const guild = client.guilds.cache.find((g) => g.id === id);

if (!guild)
  return console.log(`Can't find any guild with the ID "${id}"`);

guild.members
  .fetch()
  .then((members) =>
    members.forEach((member) => console.log(member.user.username)),
  );
```